# Помогите, пожалуйста! Я написал код с помощью цикла for, но никак не могу понять, как переписать его на while?

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
alert( `number ${i}!` );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Цикл `for` можно разбить на следующие составляющие:

```
for (<инициализатор>; <условие>; <итератор>){
    <тело>
}
```

В цикл while можно перенести так:

```
<инициализатор>
while(<условие>){
    <тело>
    <итератор>
}
```

---

```
let i = 0;
while(i < 3) {
  alert( `number ${i}!` );
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаем так:

```
пока i меньше 3, то {
    выводим строку 
}
```

Но не забываем, что `i` нужно увеличивать, иначе будет зацикливание.

```js
let i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
  alert( `number ${i}!` );
  i++;
}
```